# How to Merge Multiple PDF Files Into One PDF using php mpdf library

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3, mpdf

My Goal is to merge multiple file into single pdf file.For that I'm taking  multiple files from database with different file format.From which all JPG/PNG files are added into html page and its converted into single pdf file.

```
$dat='<html>
        <head>
            <title>Title of the document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <img src="/uploads/file_name1.PNG" width="100%" >
        <img src="/uploads/file_name2.PNG" width="100%" >
        </body>
        </html>';
        $header_data = array('header'=>'','footer'=>'');
        $this->load->library('mpdf');
        $mpdf = new mPDF('c','A4',10, 'Arial',10,10,10,10,0,0);
        $mpdf->useAdobeCJK = true;
        //$mpdf->SetAutoFont(AUTOFONT_ALL);
        $data['cmp_id']=1;
        $header_data = array('header'=>'','footer'=>'');
        $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader(array('h'=>'35','html'=>$header_data['header'],'',''));
        $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter(array('h'=>'25','html'=>$header_data['footer'],'',''));
        $mpdf->SetTitle($candidate_name);
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($dat);
        $mpdf->Output('forms.pdf','I');
```

Now I need to merge this pdf file and other pdf file taking from database using mpdf library.

otherwise all files including pdf need to comes in the html format,from which i can use  generated pdf file.When I'm adding pdf file in html(using iframe), it won't work.
Please help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you can use mpdf, but I did all this in production, on Linux, with excellent results in terms of quality, size and time as fallows:

1. all raster files are converted to PDF invoking 'convert -density 150 -strip -interlace JPEG -compress JPEG -quality 72' [file] [fileDst]'.
2. once you have all PDF files invoke 'gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/default -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dDetectDuplicateImages -dCompressFonts=true -r150 -sOutputFile=[pdfDstFile] [filesInput].

There is no need to create html files, just install required Linux packages and process input files. (please check syntax and adjust parameters, the code was simply pasted from my code)